How do I quickly and easily scatter these individual cubes away from the center, without having to separate them by loose parts? It's one object

This Rubik's cube as a whole is one object made up of 27 loose cubes. I have animated a previous section where the initially scrambled cube is solved by rotating the cubes in edit mode and keyframing them with the anim-all add-on. What I now want to do is have the cube "blow up" by scattering the cubes in different directions, away from its center. Is there a way for me to quickly achieve this without having to separate by loose parts or keyframe each cube one by one? I tried using the push/pull operator, but all this did was warp individual cubes instead of moving them around. Thank you

If you need separate parts of an object act as separate objects, the easiest solution is to just separate them into separate objects. So you should have done that in the first place before animating.
With that said, you are in a situation you are now and it's still possible to make separate parts act like separate objects. That is possible to do in a few ways. One way would be to use hook modifiers and hook each cube to a separate object. You can do that by selecting each cube's geometry in edit mode and hitting  Ctrl  +  H  and choosing Hook to New Object. The issue is you have to do that 27 times. Once you have the empties, you can animate their locations. It's easy to move them apart by scaling them
with Affect Only > Locations enabled:


You can also animate the Strength of the Hook modifiers and set them to 0 for the part where you don't want the empties to have any effects and let the cube be animated other ways.

There is also nothing wrong with hiding your cube at some frame and switching it out to a duplicate, that looks the same at that frame but consists of separated geometry that is set up in completely different way. You could do physics simulations this way for example while keeping your existing animation before that made another way.
